# segmentation fault when allocating

Tags: c++, gdb, coredump

I am getting a segmentation fault and would appreciate help trying to understand what I have done incorrectly.

After a while of my code running I have received a coredump:
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

```
struct config {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
};

static config* configuration_table = NULL;

void Album::caller() {
   
    replay(2, configuration_table, 0, false);
}

int Album::replay(int count, config*& config_tbl, unsigned int& config_sz, bool send) {
    int num_elems =0;

    ...
    ...
    ...

    err = get_num_elems(&num_elems);
    if (err) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (!num_elems) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (config_tbl) {
        delete[] config_tbl;
        config_tbl = NULL;
        config_sz = 0;
    }
    
    config_tbl = new config[num_elems];
    if (!config_tbl) {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

gdb:

## 4 0xf9abd319 in Album::replay (this=0xa693955, count=2, config_tbl=@0xf9d4299e: 0x0, config_sz=@0xa3039fe: 0, send=false)

from the backtrace it appears the problem is with malloc that comes from the operator "new" from "**config_tbl = new config[num_elems];**".
num_elems has size 15 when I debugged it.

I don't understand what I have done incorrectly. Is is possible that the system is out of memory?

Comment: please include a [mcve]. The cause for the crash is not necessarily in the same place as the crash

Comment: @idclev463035818 this is minimal reproducible. I have removed everything that is not relevant (except for function parameters)

Comment: no it is no reproducible. To compile this I would need a definition of `Album`, I would have to remove some `...` (while wondering why they are there). Maybe this isnt needed to reproduce the problem, I cannot know, but you do

Comment: somewhere you must initialize `config_tbl`. The code you posted assumes that it is either `nullptr` or a valid pointer. If you don't thats a problem

Comment: @idclev463035818 "..." is used to express that there is a lot of code in between and I don't see how the definition of "Album" is relevant for this. There is a problem with memory and as I provided all the relevant variables where the segmentation fault happens, it doesn't need to be compiled. I suspect there is an allocation in "..." that is overrun by my new allocation but not sure why it would happen -- maybe I am not familiar enough with memory allocation and this is why I am asking for help.

Comment: I just tried to explain you: This code makes an assumption about `config_tbl` that has to be ensured in other code that you did not post. I cannot know if that assumption holds or not unless you show a complete example.

Comment: concerning `Album` being relevant or not: If it is not relevant then you could remove it from the example. Currently `Album::replay` is one reason why others cannot do much with the code you posted (without modifying it)

Comment: You haven't `"...provided all the relevant variables where the segmentation fault happens"` though.  How are you using the function `Album::replay`?  What is the value of `config_tbl` passed to it -- has it been initialized correctly?

Comment: @idclev463035818 my mistake, you are correct. I have added the caller function for a more complete code and the gdb output of the frame. My mistake.

Comment: I had already lost my patience and wrote an answer ;)

Comment: @idclev463035818 It's ok, thanks

Comment: fwiw it is not clear why you insist on not posting a [mcve]. It is not possible to know what exactly causes the crash with the fragments you posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code assumes that `config_tbl` is properly initialized. As you insist that the code you posted is all that is relevant, I assume it is not properly initialized.

Consider this simplified example:

```
void foo( int* ptr) {
    if (ptr) delete ptr;
}
```

This is fine if `ptr` is either `nullptr` or a valid pointer (ie it points to an `int` created via `new`). Correct usage is either

```
foo(nullptr);
```

or

```
int* x = new int;
foo(x);
```

However, it is too easy to make `foo` go havoc:

```
int* x;
foo(x);      // UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR
int y;
foo(&y);     // BOOM
```

Do not use pointers for dynamic arrays in the first place. Use `std::vector` instead.

PS: Note that while `foo` is utterly bad code, it isn't wrong. It is the calling code that can cause a crash.